# Dynamic Reconfigure in ROS

Tags: c++, ros

I am going through the ROS tutorials for Dynamic Reconfigure. I have very little background in C++. I am having trouble understanding some lines in particular.

I have tried to go through some tutorials for C++ and boost but the jargon used is beyond by technical level. 
The exact lines are as follows:

```
dynamic_reconfigure::Server<parameter_test::parametersConfig>::CallbackType f;
f = boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2);
```

My questions are:

1) Could someone explain in simple terms what :: or the namespace resolution operator does?

2) What exactly is boost::bind() and what does it do?

3) What are the arguments _1 and _2 supposed to do?

The link for the complete file is on:

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode%28cpp%29

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question doesn't fit well for the FAQ like intended format here, it's way to broad. 1.Only one question per question please. 2. Do some research before asking, it's well documented already whet e.g. the _scope resolution operator does_, or what `boost::bind()` is for.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace resolution operator allows you to specify a "path" to the function/class/variable (by default it uses the global namespace or [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) ; here it denotes the fact that we use the `bind` from the `boost` namespace.

`boost::bind` allows you to bind (as a form of [Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)) parameters of a function.

`_1` and `_2` are placeholders for `boost::bind` that tells how to "route" the unbound parameters (those not provided as arguments of `bind`) :

```
void f(int a, int b);

auto x = boost::bind(f, _1, _2);
x(1, 2); //a=1 b=2

auto y = boost::bind(f, _2, _1);
y(1,2); //a=2 b=1
```